# Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oracle10g

I have create registration form. Through this I try to upload images and documents and save it to the database, but after inserting values through html form I got **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1**

Also I import java zoom api(.jars)into web-inf->lib folder

Server is localhost itself

Please Suggest me solution!!

```
**Home.html**

<body>

<center>
    <a href="Register.jsp">Register New Employee</a>
    <a href="View.jsp">View and Upload Employee Details</a>
</center>
</body>



**Register.jsp**

<html>
<body>

<center>
    <h1>Employee Registration Page</h1><br><br>
    <form action="RegisterServlet" method="post" 
          enctype="multipart/form-      data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tid"></td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Employee Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tname"></td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Employee Add</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="tadd"></td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Employee Photo</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="tphoto"></td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Employee Resume</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="tresume"></td> 
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="register"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>


</center>
</body>
</html>



**RegisterServlet.java**

@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String resumePath="c:/store/resumes";
    String photoPath="c:/store/photos";

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    try{
        MultipartFormDataRequest nreq=new MultipartFormDataRequest(request);

        int eId=Integer.parseInt(nreq.getParameter("tid"));
        String eName=nreq.getParameter("tname");
        String eAdd=nreq.getParameter("tadd");

        /*String ePhoto=nreq.getParameter("tphoto");
        String eResume=nreq.getParameter("tresume");*/

        UploadBean upb=new UploadBean();
        upb.setFolderstore(resumePath);
        upb.setOverwrite(false);
        upb.store(nreq,"tresume");

        upb.setFolderstore(photoPath);
        upb.setOverwrite(false);
        upb.store(nreq,"tphoto");

        Vector history=upb.getHistory();

        ArrayList<String> fileName=new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<history.size();i++){
            UploadParameters up=(UploadParameters) history.elementAt(i);
            fileName.add(up.getFilename());

            System.out.println("resume "+fileName.get(0));
            System.out.println("photo "+fileName.get(1));

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.
getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
("insert into  employeereg values(?,?,?,?,?)");

            ps.setInt(1, eId);
            ps.setString(2, eName);
            ps.setString(3, eAdd);
            ps.setString(4, resumePath+"/"+fileName.get(0));
            ps.setString(5,photoPath+"/"+fileName.get(1));

            int j=ps.executeUpdate();

                if(j==1){
                    out.println("Successfully Uploaded And Stored in
  Database");
                }
                else{
                    out.println("Failed Uploading");
                }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e);
    }
  }

}



**View.jsp**

<body>

<h1>List Of All Files Under C:\store</h1>

<%

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection   con=DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from employeereg");
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

%>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Employee Name</td><td>Employee Address</td>
<td>Employee Resume</td><td>Employee Photo</td></tr>

        <%

            while(rs.next()){
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td>
                <td>
<a href="Download.jsp?resumeId=<%=rs.getString(1) %>">Download Here</a></td>
                <td>
<a href="Download.jsp?photoId=<%=rs.getString(1) %>">Download Here</a></td>
            </tr>
            <% }%>

</table>
</body>



**Download.jsp**

<%
    String fileName="";
    String queryText="";

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.
getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");

    if(request.getParameter("resumeId")!=null)
        queryText="select emp_resume from employeereg where emp_id=
"+request.getParameter("resumeId");
    else
        queryText="select emp_pic from employeereg where emp_id=
"+request.getParameter("photoId");

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(queryText);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        fileName=rs.getString(1);

    }

    File f=new File(fileName);
    int length=0;

    ServletOutputStream op=response.getOutputStream();
    ServletContext context=getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    String mimetype=context.getMimeType(fileName);
    response.setContentType
((mimetype!=null)?mimetype:"application/octet-stream");
    response.setContentLength((int)f.length());
    response.setHeader
("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+fileName);

    byte[] bbuf=new byte[1024];

    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

    while((in!=null) && ((length=in.read(bbuf))!=-1)){
        op.write(bbuf,0,length);

    }
    in.close();
    op.flush();
    op.close();


%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a new `ArrayList` named `fileName`, added only one element to it, but accessed zeroth and first element in a `for`-loop. On the first iteration, there is no element at index 1.
I've marked two places where you've done it.

```
ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0;i<history.size();i++) {
    UploadParameters up=(UploadParameters) history.elementAt(i);
    fileName.add(up.getFilename());

    System.out.println("resume "+fileName.get(0));
    System.out.println("photo "+fileName.get(1)); /* Here */

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","manager");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into  employeereg values(?,?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setInt(1, eId);
    ps.setString(2, eName);
    ps.setString(3, eAdd);
    ps.setString(4, resumePath+"/"+fileName.get(0));
    ps.setString(5,photoPath+"/"+fileName.get(1)); /* And here */

    int j=ps.executeUpdate();

    /* ... */
```

Comment: Thanks For Yout Suggestion ....Actually It's my silly mistake that I never close for loop at right place it should close after fileName.add(up.getFilename()); this line but i forgot to close that's why it doesn't take index 1 value and throws error......But Thanks For your suggestion it helps me to find solution